# MySql Running on Windows but Cannot Connect Using Command line

Tags: mysql, windows, database-connection

I am using MySql 5.6 (64 bit, no-install) on Windows Server 2008, the service is running fine, MySql Workbench can successfully connect. But, when trying the connect using command prompt from the localhost, I am getting the following error:

e:\mysql\bin>mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: ***********

**ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)**

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Did you check that the service is started and running?

Comment: Have you checked the usual stuff, such as port number, software based firewall, etc.?

Comment: service is running fine on port 3306.

Comment: Do you have admin rights in command prompt?

Comment: Yes, "Run as Administrator" is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem by myself.

MySql was bound to listen to only a fixed IP of the Windows Server (e.g. 10.33.40.26). Adding a localhost alias for that IP in the Windows "hosts" file solved the problem.

10.33.40.26       localhost

The location of the hosts file can vary on different versions of windows; here's how the file finally looked like in my case after the modification:

```
C:\>more c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.33.40.26       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Open services (`Start->Run-> "services.msc"`) and check if MySQL is running. If it's not - run it.

If it is running already, then most likely you have a firewall blocking connections to port 3306 (or whichever port you decided to have MySQL running at) and you need to allow incoming connections to that port then (allowing connections depends on what software you're using).

Comment: I mentioned that service is properly running, even can connect using workbench client. Just checked from remote machine, was able to connect, so not a firewall issue. But local command prompt in the server is still unable to connect. This is causing inconvenience as mysqldump is also not usable.